# In the POSIX semop() arguments, what is the meaning of sem_flg = 0

Tags: c, linux, semaphore

I was checking the `semop()` function and the flag value of structure `sembuf` could be either SEM_UNDO or  IPC_NOWAIT.  So in the case that we pass flag value as 0 then what will be the behavior? Somewhere I read it was a no operation. What does that mean? Can anyone explain?

Comment: Do Nothing means it will be waiting indefinitly(making the process hang) or it will start working after some time ?

Comment: `sem_flg` holds a couple of different bits as you pointed out in your post. If those bits are zero, then whatever the manual page for `semop` says it does when those bits are set will not happen. That's what's meant by "do nothing". It's not a `semop` will do nothing. It's an indication that the flags it would represent won't be activated.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to make this active. Actually i tried this using code, when i press ctrl+c first time code stops execution but when i run second time it just hangs the process. I have made this as daemon process. i need to reboot machine or restart daemon to make it work. any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do is to read the specification — the POSIX specification for [`semop()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/semop.html) explains it all.

If the flag is 0, it means that the operation may cause the process to hang waiting for the semaphore to become available (if the flag included `IPC_NOWAIT`, it would not hang), and it also means that the semaphore value will not be adjusted to undo the operation if the process crashes (if the flag included `SEM_UNDO`, the system would record the information necessary to undo the semaphore operation.
Whether that's considered safe or not is up to you.